# Component is not rendering in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why this component is not rendering in react js.It shows the error message
**Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports**.

This is my component

```
function Test({session}) {
    const RenderPage=fetchComment &&(
                fetchComment?.map((comment)=>{
                    return <LoadComment
                    key={i}
                    timestamp={comment.timestamp?.toDate()}
                    comment={comment.comment}
                    image={comment.image}
                    user={comment.user} />
                })
                )
return (
<RenderPage></RenderPage>
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return (
{RenderPage}
)
```

change the return statement. since its a variable not a component.

Answer (score 2):

`RenderPage` isn't a valid React component, it is either falsey if `fetchComment` is undefined/falsey, or it is an array of JSX. Just return the computed `RenderPage` value. I suggest also un-PascalCasing the variable to alleviate any future reading confusion, convert back to camelCase. And to cover the case where you aren't returning an array, conditionally return `null` for valid JSX return from `Test` component.

```
function Test({session}) {
  const renderPage = fetchComment ? fetchComment.map((comment, i) => {
    return (
      <LoadComment
        key={i}
        timestamp={comment.timestamp?.toDate()}
        comment={comment.comment}
        image={comment.image}
        user={comment.user}
      />
    );
  }) : null;
  return renderPage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
export default Test({session}) {
const RenderPage=fetchComment &&(
            fetchComment?.map((comment)=>{
                return <LoadComment
                key={i}
                timestamp={comment.timestamp?.toDate()}
                comment={comment.comment}
                image={comment.image}
                user={comment.user} />
            })
            )
return (
   {RenderPage}
 )
```

}

Comment: Thanks it all works.In morning I had tried the same process but not worked.I think I had forgot to save.